# Unable to display docker web form using apache

Tags: apache, docker

I am new to Docker and am trying to create a simple form to be built with Docker and displayed through my localhost. When I `docker-compose up` I am not getting any errors, but when I go into my browser and go to `localhost:5003`, I get a "Unable to connect" page. I was under the impression that I would be able to see the immediate result on my localhost:5003. I have included the files and the paths to those files. Any direction is much appreciated.

**/docker_test/form/api.py**

```
# docker test 

from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request
#from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, validators, StringField, SubmitField

app= Flask(__name__)
#api= Api(app)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '7d441f27d441f27567d441f2b6176a'
#@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])

class UserForm(Form):
    salutation= TextField('Salutation:', validators= [validators.required()])
    first_name= TextField('First Name:', validators= [validators.required()])
    last_name= TextField('Last Name:', validators= [validators.required()])

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def welcome():
    form = UserForm(request.form)
    print(form.errors)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        salutation=request.form['salutation']
        first_name=request.form['first_name']
        last_name=request.form['last_name']
        print(salutation)
        print(first_name)
        print(last_name)

        if form.validate():
            flash('Welcome' + salutation + last_name)
        else:
            flash('Please fill in the required fields.')
    return render_template("index.php", form=form)

#api.add_resource(UserForm, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

**/docker_test/form/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Docker Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
            {% if messages %}
                <ul>
                    {% for message in messages %}
                        <li>{{ message[1] }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        <form action="" method="post">
            {{ form.csrf }}

            <div class="input text">
                {{ form.salutation.label }} {{ form.salutation }}
            </div>

            <div class="input text">
                {{ form.first_name.label }} {{ form.first_name }}
            </div>

            <div class="input text">
                {{ form.last_name.label }} {{ form.last_name }}
            </div>

            <div class="input submit">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**/docker_test/form/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3-onbuild
COPY . /usr/src/app
CMD ["python", "api.py"]
```

**/docker_test/form/requirements.txt**

```
Flask==0.12
flask-restful==0.3.5
wtforms==2.2
```

**/docker_test/docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  form-service:
    build: ./form
    volumes:
      - ./form:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 5001:80

  website:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    volumes:
      - ./website:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 5003:80
    depends_on:
      - form-service
```

**Output of docker ps -a**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                  NAMES
9e434e098a48        php:apache                 "docker-php-entryp..."   24 minutes ago      Exited (0) 20 seconds ago                             tutorial_website_1
9af857e393f9        tutorial_product-service   "python api.py"          30 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes                  0.0.0.0:5001->80/tcp   tutorial_product-service_1
3a072f6493f1        ubuntu:latest              "/bin/bash"              3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                                dockertest_website_1
75e4520d2878        dockertest_form-service    "python api.py"          4 hours ago         Exited (0) About an hour ago                          dockertest_form-service_1
d30ba94db492        c783acf7c95e               "/bin/sh -c 'pip i..."   3 days ago          Exited (1) 3 days ago                                 peaceful_hodgkin
899f1a2db5ae        292ed8dee366               "/bin/sh -c '#(nop..."   3 days ago          Created                                               jolly_hugle
```

Comment: Your "website" container doesn't do anything.  (If you look at something like `docker ps -a` you'll probably see it exited.)  Did you intend for it to run something like an Apache image?

Comment: I want it to display the form fields and allow the user to submit their info- submission will just lead to a welcome message to flash within the same page.

Comment: can you please post the output of 'docker ps -a' command?

Comment: I added it to the question. I apologize I couldn't get it to format into a table it's supposed to be.

Comment: opHASnoName has generously formatted the table for me.